# How can I add a repeating schedule to send to the masterRegistryActor

Tags: scala, akka

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val rootBehavior = Behaviors.setup[Nothing] { context =>
      val masterRegistryActor = context.spawn(Master(), "MasterActor")
      context.watch(masterRegistryActor)

      masterRegistryActor ! Master.Watchlist("TSLA")
      masterRegistryActor ! Master.Watchlist("NVDA")

      Behaviors.empty
    }

    implicit val system = ActorSystem[Nothing](rootBehavior, AppConfig.name)
    implicit val executionContext = system.executionContext

}
```

I am using akka typed as you can see, and I want to understand how I can do the following:

1. How can I schedule on a repeated timeframe, currently I can only do this:

   system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds, masterRegistryActor, Master.WatchList("AAPLE"))

I did this inside of the Behaviors.Setup, for some reason the system.scheduler.schedule(...) API is not available, why and how do I get around this?

2. My other confusion is, since my masterRegistryActor is inside of my rootBehavior, how can I reference it from the outside?   I wanted to make this actor available throughout my application kind of like a root/global actor but this is the only way I found how to spawn it.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that `Master` is actually a `Behavior[MasterMessage]` and is defined like following

```scala
trait MasterMessage
case object RepeatMasterMessage extends MasterMessage

object Master {
  def apply[MasterMessage]() =
    Behaviors.setup { context => 
      // master behaviour
    }
}
```

Then you can just wrap the `Master` behaviour into a `Behaviors.withTimer`.

```scala
trait MasterMessage
case object RepeatMasterMessage extends MasterMessage

case object RepeatMasterMessageTimerKey

object Master {
  def apply[MasterMessage]() =
    Behaviors.withTimer[MasterMessage] { timerScheduler =>

      timerScheduler.startTimerWithFixedDelay(
        RepeatMasterMessageTimerKey,
        RepeatMasterMessage,
        Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        Duration(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      )

      Behaviours.setup[MasterMessage] { context => 
        // master behaviour
      }
    }
}
```